# How to run javascript function without having client be on the page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a settimeout function that basically removes an object from my database when the time runs out for that user. However, this only works when the client navigates to the page as that is when that settimeout function runs. This is kind of buggy because say the user navigates to my page, the settimeout is invoked and the countdown starts but if the user now navigates to a different page or closes the web app, even if the time has run out for the user, the settimeout function won't go ahead and delete the object from the db unless the user comes back to that same page, at which point again the settimeout function would get invoked and would detect that time has run out and then it will go ahead and delete the object from the DB.

How can I keep that javascript function running, essentially offline? So instead, the settimeout function should delete that object from my DB without having the user navigate to the page

Comment: Presumably your DB is serverside, right? Why would you rely on a clientside function to trigger something that is clearly a serverside maintenance task? Essentially seems like you want to reimplement sessions. Store the last access for each user in their DB object; when next accessed, check if it is more than certain age, if so delete it. In the meantime, you can also have a `cron` job that will clean up things that haven't been accessed in a long time.

Comment: Also, why is there a timeout attached to it at all? Is this something the user can stop if they so wished? I agree with Amadan though, it should really be moved to the server side.

Comment: I'm using Firebase DB and the reason I have this on client side is because I need to update the html with the time remaining from when the user navigates to the page. If I move this settimeout function to the server side to delete the object, I can't render my page again to update the time remaining div that I have in my HTML

Comment: First, if you want the object to be removed from the database at some future time whether the user is still on the current web page or not, then that's a server-side function.  Set a timer on the server and remove it when the timer fires.  Second, if you want to show a countdown in the client, that's a completely separate UI problem.  When the page is rendered, it can be initialized with the time remaining on any timer and it can then use its own timer to show the time remaining in the web page.  Or, the page can query the back-end with Ajax to request info on any timers it should show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and efficient solution is to store the time this database object is created at along with the object. For example, if you are storing a `Cat` object in your database, store a field on the object for the timestamp at which it was created.

Whenever the user tries to access the database object, compare the current time to the stored object time (on the server, preferably). If the amount of time passed is greater than however the object should live for, delete the object. Some pseudocode:

```
if (currentTime() - object.creationTime >= lifeTime)
    object.destroy();
```

This also solves the issue the asker mentioned in the question's comments about displaying a "remaining time" UI element because this creation time can also be sent to the client (along with the object) and the client can do the same process of finding how long it has been since the object was created to determine how long the object has left.

---

It's also advisable to have some process that occasionally checks the database for expired objects to make sure that clients who never come back don't leave permanent objects in the database when those objects should expire.